# What's the best way to handle multiple languages via React Router v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'd like to have multiple languages on my page. I'd like to do it via React and React Router v5. What's the best way to handle this?

This is simple code of my current routing:

```
const Routing = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Header/>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
            <Footer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
};
```

Comment: Do you want to have the slug with a different language as well?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the best. For example /en/about etc.

Comment: I mean like in english = `/about-us`, dutch = `/over-ons`

Answer (score 1):

I would approach like this: have the site copy in external files for each language, e.g. `/lang/en.json`, `/lang/fr.json` etc. Put the copy for each page in an object in that json file so you can pass just that section to the component, e.g:

```
{
  "about": {
    "header": "About"
    "intro": "..."
  }
}
```

Detect or set the language and load the correct file and put it into the routers state:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`/lang/${this.state.lang}.json`).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    this.setState({ translations: data });
  });
}
```

Then you pass what you need to the component as a property:

```
const Routing = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header/>
      <Route exact path='/' component={ () => <Home copy={ this.state.translations.home } /> }/>
      <Route path='/about' component={ () => <About copy={ this.state.translations.about } /> }/>
      <Footer/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
};
```

With this approach you don't recreate the same component for multiple languages.

**UPDATE:**

To have a lang prefix in the URL you could simplify the whole thing:

```
const Routing = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header/>
      <Route exact path='/:lang' component={ Home }/>
      <Route path='/:lang/about' component={ About } /> }/>
      <Footer/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
};
```

That parameter them becomes available in the component as `this.props.match.params.lang` which you can use to load the language file for that component, e.g. `/lang/s{this.props.match.params.lang}/about.json`

Comment: With this solution my URL will be always the same. I'd like to have lang prefix in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use /:lng before route like -

```
<Route path="/:lng/" exact component={Home} />
```

You can read more about it - https://medium.com/@markuretsky/react-router-multilingual-362eaa33ae20